# What is the behavior of AtomicPtr::compare_exchange when used on a pointer to a struct?

Tags: rust, concurrency, compare-and-swap

Does this usage of `compare_exchange` produce defined behavior?

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicPtr, Ordering};

struct Dummy {
    foo: i64,
    bar: i64,
}

fn main() {
    let ptr = &mut Dummy { foo: 1, bar: 2 };
    let some_ptr = AtomicPtr::new(ptr);

    let other_ptr = &mut Dummy { foo: 10, bar: 10 };

    let value = some_ptr.compare_exchange(ptr, other_ptr, Ordering::SeqCst, Ordering::Relaxed);
}
```

If it is defined, what is the defined behavior? Will Rust use double width CAS for the above operation on supported architectures like x86_64?

Comment: `AtomicPtr::compare_exchange` only compares and swaps the _pointer_, which is 64-bit and there is no reason for double-with CAS.

Comment: Yep my understanding of compare_exchange was wrong. Thanks for clearing it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this usage of `compare_exchange` produce defined behavior?

Barring a bug in the compiler or the standard library, safe Rust should never result in undefined behavior in the C and C++ sense. Additionally, creating and manipulating pointers is always safe, it's only dereferencing them or converting them to references that requires explicit `unsafe` because the programmer needs to provide guarantees that the compiler cannot verify. Whether a particular call  to a safe function does what you expect is another matter, of course.

> If it is defined, what is the defined behavior?

The behavior is that specified by the documentation: the address `some_ptr` points to is compared to the one `ptr` points to and, if they match, `some_ptr` is atomically updated to point to the address provided by `other_ptr`. The previous pointer is returned in either case. Since your code initializes `some_ptr` from `ptr` and doesn't create a thread that could change it, it will result in `some_ptr` pointing to the address provided by `other_ptr`, and returning `ptr`.

> Will Rust use double width CAS for the above operation on supported architectures like x86_64?

`AtomicPtr::compare_exchange()` only compares and swaps the pointer, which is as wide as `usize` (64 bits on modern hardware) and there is no reason for double-width CAS.

But I think I understand how the confusion might have arisen: the docs of `compare_exchange` speak of *value* of a pointer. This "value" is not the value of the pointed-to data, it's just the underlying `*mut T` pointer, which only represents a memory address. Just like an `AtomicBool`'s value is `bool`, an `AtomicPtr` value is a pointer.

The docs would be slightly more precise if they spoke of the "address <x> points to" instead of "value of <x>", but that's more verbose. (The shorter "address of <pointer>" would again be ambiguous because it might be understood to refer to the address where the pointer itself is held.)